# Redeliver message to MQ when using @JmsListener

Tags: spring, jms, listener, ibm-mq

I'm using @EnableJms and @JmsListener annotation to register a queue listener in my application, basing on [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jms) tutorial. I'm connecting to IBM MQ, getting connection factory using jndi. I have read about acknowledge modes etc. but still it's a new thing to me. And my problem is that the message is not being returned to a queue (the listener is never called again).

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory 
      = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); //I have tried also CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE
    return factory;
}


@JmsListener(containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory", destination = "myQueue")
@SendTo("secondQueue")
public String testListener(String message){
 if(true) throw new NullPointerException();
 else return message;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
I would have also a second question. From what I understand if I would like to implement any operation on a database, only way to rollback a commit (if something went wrong after this) would be to create a transaction manager? If not, I would need to detect a duplicated message.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  The answer provided by @artild would have me understand that you are attempting to cause a failure so you can see the message to back to the queue, is this correct?

Comment: If a session is Transacted, then after you read/process the message you must call commit to have it removed from the queue.  The SessionAcknowledgeMode is only used for non-Transacted sessions, it is ignored for Transacted sessions.  There is a special value that you can use to better indicate that it is ignored, it is `Session.TRANSACTED` but the value in this field will never matter for a Transacted session.   `Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` would only apply to non-Transacted sessions.

Comment: From a IBM MQ standpoint both Transacted and non-Transacted with `Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` are similar, the big difference is that Transacted sessions can include writes in the transaction.  With IBM MQ this means you could have the Listener consume a message and then for example put it to a second queue, if they are both on the same queue manager then the commit will make both the GET and PUT of the message happen as one unit of work, this can not be done with non-Transacted with `Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`.

Comment: If in my example the queues are on two different queue managers, or like your second question if you consume the message and then want to update a database, these would need a transaction manager.  It is the job of the transaction manager to handle committing the GET from the queue and the PUT to a second queue or UPDATE to the database as a single unit of work.

Comment: Note that if you have access to view the messages on the queue you can check the backout count of a message to see how many times it has been rolled back to the queue.

Comment: The Backout queues and thresholds mentioned in @artild's answer are meant to handle a poison message situation, for example something in the message causes your process to crash, if you setup backout queues and Threshold you can cause the IBM MQ classes for JMS to move the message  to a secondary back out queue if the backout count has reached a threshold, the goal being to get the poison message out of the way so you can process the next message on the queue.

Comment: If the reason the processing of the message failed is because of something like a database being down, then you would just end up sending all messages to the backout queue, so you need to be sure you have in place a process to handle the backout queue messages.  Some applications depend on message order, having backout queues enabled could cause out of order processing.  Think of an example of a message to transfer money and a second message to cancel the transfer, if you didn't handle it what would happen if the cancel message was processed first?

Comment: If your queue has a backout threshold greater than zero, the IBM MQ JMS classes move the message either to defined backout queue or to the dead letter queue. Can you give use the output of following MQSC commands: `display qlocal('myQueue') bothresh boqname` and `display qmgr deadq`?

Comment: Here is the reference to my previous comment: [Handling poison messages in IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032280_.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. First, I had backout threshold set to 0 on myQueue, and then set to 5. In both cases I couldn't see a message being redelivered (listener being called again). Backout queue field is empty. From what I understand, the message should be moved to backout queue/dlq when the threashold is exceeded. In my case, at least when set to 5, it shouldn't.

Comment: @JoshMc, thanks for the explanation. Should I call commit/rollback programatically? I thought it should be done automatically.. I'm using setSessionTransacted(true), when I'm checking factory object inside the listener I can see that it's set to true.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to test backout queue logic or are you trying to consume messages?  If you want automatic acknowledgment, like I said above you would need to have to have `setSessionTransacted(false)` for `setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)` to have any purpose.

Comment: Regarding your comment about backout thresholds: `BOTHRESH(0)` disables the functionality and messages are always put back to the queue when there is a failure, with `BOTHRESH(5)` and a blank `BOQNAME`, JMS will attempt to put to the queue specified in the `QMGR DEADQ` setting.  If the app can not inquire the `QMGR DEADQ` value, or if it can, if the value is empty or populated with a queue that either does not exist or the app does not have permission to, the message will still go back to the queue.  Check the BO count of the messages on the queue to see if they are being backed out.

Comment: I'm trying to test backout logic. When message is consumed by listener and exception is thrown, listener is not called the second time and the queue is empty- I don't know how could I check the backout count of the message.

Comment: I have created SessionAwareMassageListener, and from what I see session. getTransacted() method returns false. Not sure if I'm mixing terms, but shouldn't it be set to true?

Comment: adolzi, unles you put "@JoshMc" in the comment I will not know you sent it unless I checked the question again.  What are the values of `BOTHRESH` and `BOQNAME`?  If you want it to back out to a specific backout queue you need to specify a non 0 `BOTHRESH` value and fill in the name of the queue you want messages to backout to in `BOQNAME`.  The application needs `passall` permission to the backout queue.  If the `BOQNAME` is empty or it fails for any reason to put to the named queue it will then try to backout to the DLQ you must have `passall`.

Comment: If it also can not put to the DLQ for any reason (you don't have permission, it is full, the qmgr does not have one specified, etc) then the message will just be put back on the original queue.  For checking the backout count of the message, do you have access to the queue manager itself?  Are you the MQ  Admin?

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

First set the acknowledgement mode to `Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`
and when receiving the messages, if it's processed correctly then just call `message.acknowledge()` method or else don't call.

It will automatically stay in the queue and you don't need to resend it.

You need to use

```
import javax.jms.Message
```

Answer (score 0):

I created simple Spring Boot app and Docker container of IBM MQ to test your case.
I found good instructions in this tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-jms-application-development-with-spring-boot/

And in your case this environment behaves as expected: endless cycle of receive message -> NullPointerException -> return message -> ...

Than I found feature of IBM MQ called "Backout Queues & Thresholds", you'll found the explanation in this blog post: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/imwuc/browse/blogs/blogviewer?BlogKey=28814801-083d-4c80-be5f-90aaaf81cdfb

Briefly, it is possible to restrict number of times message returned to queue after exception, and after this limit send message to another queue.

May be in your case this feature used on your destination queue.